# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^z}$ diverges if $0 <\Re(z) < 1$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have been trying to solve this problem for more that two days and yet i have no idea of what to do. I am trying to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^z}$ diverges if 0 < $\Re(z)  < 1$.

If $z$ is real it turns out to be very simple because

$\int_n^{n+1} \frac{dt}{t^z} \leq \frac{1}{n^z}$  and $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{dt}{t^z}$ diverges.

But for arbitrary $z \in \mathbb{C}$ the same idea turns out in a mess, the hint is: analyze  $\sum_n^{\infty} \big(\frac{1}{n^z} - \int_n^{n+1} \frac{dt}{t^z} \big) $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your hint should be "analyse
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{n^z}-\int_n^{n+1}\frac{dt}{t^z}\right)".$$
Integrating by parts,
$$\frac1{n^z}-\int_n^{n+1}\frac{dt}{t^z}
=z\int_n^{n+1}\frac{n+1-t}{t^{z+1}}\,dt.$$
If $z=x+iy$ then this integral is $O(n^{-x-1})$. As $x>0$.
the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{n^z}-\int_n^{n+1}\frac{dt}{t^z}\right)$$
converges absolutely, but
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_n^{n+1}\frac{dt}{t^z}$$
diverges, and so
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^z}$$
must diverge.